# Let $\lim_{x\to \infty} |f(x)|= \infty$, Then: $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= \infty$ OR $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)= -\infty$

Tags: calculus

I know the statment is false but I cant find a good counter exemple, this is what I've tried:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $x \in \mathbb Q$} \\
-x, & \text{if $x \notin \mathbb Q$}
\end{cases}
$$
so $\lim_{x\to \infty} |f(x)|= \infty$ , and I want to express my function using Dirichlet function (which I already know that its limit does not exist), but I can't figure out how. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be rather easy to show directly by the definition, without the Dirichlet function, that your function does neither go to $\infty$ nor to $-\infty$. You know that in each real interval, there is a rational number, so the function has positive and negative values in each interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ the Dirichlet function. Then you have
$$ f(x) = x \cdot (2 \cdot D(x) - 1) \qquad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb R.$$
Intuitively you scale it with factor $2$, shift it $1$ unit down to get a function which is $1$ on $\mathbb Q$ and $-1$ on $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ so you can multiply it by $x$ to get the wanted function :)